# Heart monitor sensor / Photoplethysmography

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm comparing several health monitor bands and their sensors in the market.

What is a [Photoplethysmograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoplethysmogram#Photoplethysmograph) sensor, and how does it compare to the [Optical Heart Rate Sensor](http://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-band/en-us/support/hardware/specifications) in MS Band?

Is there an MVP for Microsoft Band yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HR sensor on the band is actually a PPG sensor.